# How does one find such a number?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Not really one of those who usually ask for help here, but this case seems to be too much for me. I have been going over Courant’s “Differential and Integral Calculus”, and I have finally reached the problems section of the chapter 1.5 (i.e. “The limit of a sequence”). I would not have come here if it hasn’t been for the problem 9, namely the (e) part of it. The problem is generally about the sequence $a_n = \frac{10^n}{n!}$. I have, as all the parts (a)-(d) asked me to, found the limit of the mentioned sequence (=0), concluded whether it is monotonic or not, found the value of n such that the sequence is monotonic onwards and estimated the difference between the sequence and its limit respectively. Now, the (e) part demands that I calculate the exact value of n such that the difference mentioned is less than $\frac{1}{100}$. I have attempted to expand the factorial and try to deduce some helpful corollaries, but that does not seem to work. I am genuinely confused by this problem and not certain how I should approach it. It is of utmost importance that I note the following: I do not require the solution, I only need a HINT. Not a very crucial one, which virtually solves it (the problem), but one sufficient enough to proceed. I should be grateful for any help provided.

P.S. Please excuse me for some fairly probable mistakes in my writing (happens for I am not a native).

Comment: Are you asking for some $n$ such that $\frac {10^n}{n!}<.01$ or the least possible such $n$?  In any case, these values are easy to compute, why not just do a search?

Comment: Should say:  you can use Sterling's formula to approximate the factorial, and work from there...but I doubt that is any easier than the simple search and, as it is only an approximation, you would still need to search for the exact answer.

Comment: @lulu On the matter of your question: it asks me for the least value of n such that the mentioned inequality holds. About performing a search: the book was written by a german mathematician in the 1930s. Not certain whether performing such searches was possible without any computational machinery (which only started to emerge in the 1940s). Pretty sure the author asks for an analytic approach.

Comment: @lulu Not quite sure if it should be the proper way of approaching the problem. Not only does it bring us to an approximate solution, but it would also be very strange using asymptotic formulas not having even introduced any asymptotics earlier in the book.

Comment: Well...you have to use something.  If you rule out direct computations and you rule out asymptotics, not sure what that leaves.  In any case, you can do the search with pencil and paper if you insist.  Just note that $a_{n}=a_{n-1}\times \frac {10}n$ so it is always easy to get the next value.  The answer is a bit further in than one would like for a hand computation, but it is still doable.

Comment: To state the obvious:  since the ratio is $\frac {10}n$, the terms actually increase until $n>10$.  indeed, $a_{10}\sim 2750$.  After that it decreases monotonically, but as you are starting from a fairly high value it takes a while to get small. Just the way it is.

Comment: @lulu I have already noticed that (yes, that was quite obvious considering the previous parts of the problem). However, that does not seem to be of consequence.

Comment: It means that the answer can not be terribly small.

Comment: In any case, it's hard to guess what techniques someone had in mind back then.  Perhaps they would have had access to a table of factorials...that would make the problem trivial. Or perhaps they were just more used to tedious, but elementary, computations than we are.

Comment: @lulu I have, actually, looked up the answer. It turns out to be 30. Now I am genuinely curious what sort of table contained 30! (which is about a 32-digit number).

Comment: Or they did it by hand. As I say, it's tedious, but elementary.  Not sure it is terribly interesting....nor is the Simpson's Formula version terribly enlightening.  You could, however, do it that way with a slide rule.

Comment: *Now I am genuinely curious what sort of table contained 30! (which is about a 32-digit number)* --- My [1972 20th edition CRC tables](https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/XJ8AAOSwvddfqBHg/s-l200.jpg), purchased in 1973 and which a large minority of math/physics students had a copy of back then (and pretty much everyone knew about it), has on p. 49 5-significant figure values for the factorials of the first $100$ positive integers and 6-significant figure values for their base-$10$ logarithms. The 1968 Schaum's Outline Mathematical Handbook **(continued)**

Comment: has 6-significant figure values for the factorials of the first $100$ positive integers, with exact values for the first $30$ positive integers (CRC has exact values for the first $20$ on p. 48). And these are by no means very specialized tables, being something that many undergraduates would either have or know someone who did. That said, I doubt the intent of the problem was to look up values in a table.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) by hand shouldn't take long, and you don't need to include that work in your answer. Once you have $n$ such that $\frac{10^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}>\frac1{100}>\frac{10^n}{n!}$, you have the answer with proof.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer for the inverse ratio, $\dfrac{n!}{10^n}$.

Taking the logarithm and using the simplest Stirling approximation, we first solve

$$n\ln n-n-n\ln10\approx0,$$ or $$n\approx 100e=27.18\cdots$$ which tells us where the ratio is near $1$ (and we still need a factor $100$). So $n=27$ is a by-default approximation.

As more precisely $$\frac{27!}{10^{27}}=10.88\cdots$$ it suffices to evaluate the partial products of

$$\frac{27!}{10^{27}}\cdot2.8\cdot2.9\cdot3.0\cdot3.1\cdots$$ and three factors will do.

Comment: OK. I couldn't have known that.

Comment: Known what precisely ?

Comment: I was replying to a comment to my A from the proposer that they had not covered integration yet, but I put it here by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

How to narrow it down. A crude lower bound: If $n\ge 2$ then  $$\ln (n!)=\sum_{j=2}^n\ln j>$$ $$>\sum_{j=2}^n\int_{j-1}^j(\ln t)dt=$$ $$=\int_1^n(\ln t)dt=(n\ln n)-n+1=$$ $$=F(n).$$

We have $a_n<1/100\iff (n+2)\ln 10<\ln (n!).$ Hence  $(n+2)\ln 10<F(n)\implies a_n<1/100.$ And we have $$(n+2)\ln 10<F(n)\iff (1+\frac2n) \ln (10e) <(\ln n)+\frac 3n.$$ Since $\ln (10e)\approx 3.3$ and $\ln (36)=2\ln 2+2\ln 3\approx (2)(0.7)+2(1.1)=3.6,$ it appears that $n\ge 36$ would suffice to make $a_n<1/100$.  But $F(n)$ is a crude lower bound for $\ln (n!)$ so it seems we should work $down$ from $36.$

In fact we have $F(30)<32\ln 10<\ln (30!).$

Comment: Excuse me, but I am currently dealing with the limits of sequences. Not even functions of continuous variables. I have not even approached integral by a slightest bit!